# RxJS compare db object to initial and emit every second

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to get an object from db and compare it to initial object, then I show a modal that say there's changes before editing. I want to use RxJS from a promise and emit the object to subscribers and compare it. The problem currently is in my observer: is just repeating the value but not searching again.

```
    const search = (initialObj: any) => {
        return from(this.api.users.getOne(initialObj)).pipe(delay(1000), repeat());
    };
    search().subscribe(d => d == initialObj);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're calling `search().subscribe()` without passing anything to the `search()` function. Shouldn't you do something like `search(initialObj).subscribe()`? Maybe your api is not even being called. Also, why are you using `repeat()`? And why the `delay(1000)`?

Comment: I just forget to pass a parameter to search, but it's not the problem. Delay and repeat was a try to repeat the db search

Comment: I'm not very familiar with repeat() operator but as an alternative I would suggest using timer() to do the request each second and check response - https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/timer